# Image slider working locally but completely absent on upload

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm a novice web designer. For a friend, I recently customized a site from a free template. At the top of the page is a JS Image Slider, which appears right as rain when a browser preview is done via my WYSIWYG tool.

However, the slider disappears completely once uploaded. Nothing is present in that space and the content below the slider is pushed upward. Unfortunately, I lack the necessary skills to troubleshoot this issue. What do you need from me to help?

The web address is http://www.michianamemories.com

Comment: The developer console (F12) shows several 404 errors for your slider's images. In addition, the first image when the slider appears is [`images/1.jpg`](http://www.michianamemories.com/images/1.jpg), which works, but its dot on the slider links to [`images/1.JPG`](http://www.michianamemories.com/images/1.JPG), which 404s.

Comment: John - I've double-checked all the images paths and I don't see an error. Not sure I understood the second half of your diagnosis. "but its dot on the slider links to images/1.JPG, which 404s." What am I missing?

Comment: John - Sorry, I'm a little slow. I've changed the file extensions to ".jpg" as opposed to ".JPG" but the issue remains.

Comment: Your slider is programmed strangely. Using developer tools to inspect the HTML (which you should be doing), after clicking any dot, [two images show up](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VJoJf.png) in the image container. In the screenshot, I'm highlighting one: it's invisible. The container object has an `overflow:hidden;` rule, and since both images are overflowing, they're hidden. [Disabling that rule](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eCRaq.jpg) makes both images show up, side by side.

Comment: The `ps_image_wrapper` is having its width set to 0 by something when you click one of the dots. Disabling that rule makes the image show up. I suspect the animation where it slims down to 0px is the culprit: it's simply never being reversed. Also, the _wrong_ image may show up (the image matching the _previous_ dot sits there). I imagine the animations are a bit goofed up: the previous image is meant to slide out of view, with the new one sliding in, but instead the previous image slides _into_ view, and the new one is sitting outside the panel hidden.

Comment: [There's an FAQ section on reputation.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) Edit: I could compile my comments into an answer but come to think of it this question is actually too localised (on account of being helpful to you, but not to future/other visitors). Perhaps leave it til I help you out in a future question perhaps. :)

Answer (score 1):

The CSS rule:

```
.ps_container{
display:none;
width:656px;
height:345px;
margin:20px auto 80px auto;
position:relative;
background:url(../images/slider_bg.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

Is setting the div with class ps_container's display to none, when I remove that `display:none` in my browser inspector the photo slider will appear.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, Kieran. I removed the "display:none" coding from the CSS and re-uploaded. The slider is still absent at www.michianamemories.com

Comment: And, actually, removing that piece of code removes the slider from my web preview in Dreamweaver too.

Comment: really? I still see it on the site, e.g. [this screenshot](http://oi43.tinypic.com/292s6dj.jpg)

Comment: Kiernan - I restored the initial coding when the display: none did not restore the slider. For the sake of being thorough, I double-checked the fix again with the same result. For the sake of troubleshooting, I  re-uploaded the coding AGAIN with the display: none removed.

Comment: @Joe Re-upload the CSS with the `display:none;` removed (or replaced with `display:block;`) instead of overriding it via JavaScript, as you seem to be doing, and see if it helps. The slider _does_ show up for me once the JavaScript overrides the `display:none;`. (Also, instead of referring to "the coding", you should probably say "the HTML" or "the CSS" or "the JavaScript", since this is the web and we have _three_ kinds of "coding").